# Parts of mathematics not yet formalized / Isabelle wishlist

Tags: isabelle

I'm curious what the current "status" in formalizing mathematics is, if maybe there is some kind of trend to prove results from a certain area of mathematics, or if there is coordinated effort to prove something?
Browsing through the Archive of Formal Proofs it seems to me that that is not the case, since various people are chiseling away at formalizing various parts of mathematics, but not in a coordinate manner (not that that would necessarily be needed, I am just curious).

Are there parts of mathematics, or major theorems, that are not yet formalized and currently very high on the wishlist?

---

In particular, in the field of (ordinary) differential equations not too much seems to have been done - but my (very naive) impression is that formalizing these results is devishly difficult since the kind of epsilon-delta reasoning that is frequently encountered does not lend itself easily to formalization, especially because already the mathematics itself is often done in a more handy-waving manner in this field (in contrast to the more algebraic parts of mathematics which typically are more precisely written done and -I'm guessing- a shade less tedious to formalize). Is this impression correct?

Answer (score 3):

Just off the top of my head:

- There is [Freek Wiedijk's list of 100 interesting theorems](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/100/) and various people have been working on formalising theorems from that list (including me), but that is mostly for fun.
- There are also ongoing efforts (mainly by Larry Paulson) to port results from HOL Light (mostly complex analysis, but also topology and geometry).
- People from Innsbruck have been working on a great number of things related to polynomials (see e.g. [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-43144-4_24)); mostly, I think, because they needed it for termination proofs in rewriting systems
- There is the [CAVA project](https://cava.in.tum.de/) that works on formalised automata and model checking

There isn't really a ‘grand Isabelle council’ that chooses an area of mathematics on which everyone shall focus for the next few years, but there are certain projects and groups that do this more or less independently of one another.

As for ordinary differential equations, [Fabian Immler](http://home.in.tum.de/~immler/) has been doing a lot of impressive work on that in the last few years. He is currently working on the proof that the Lorentz Attractor is truly chaotic, which requires quite a bit of sophisticated ODE-related material and algorithms.

You are correct that ε-δ-arguments are an absolute horror to formalise, which is why we don't do that. Limits and derivatives in Isabelle are formalised with respect to *filters* (see e.g. [here](http://home.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/~hoelzl/html-data/documents/hoelzl2013typeclasses.pdf)), which are a very elegant way to express this sort of reasoning.

As for things that would be nice to have and that, to my knowledge, nobody is working on right now:

- Pretty much anything on Freek Wiedijk's list that hasn't been done in Isabelle yet
- It would be nice to have more abstract algebra in Isabelle. (One of the reasons why we don't have that much algebra may be because the Coq people have a lot of it already; it may also be just nicer to do this with dependent types)
- There's not a lot of number theory
- A theory of manifolds and vector analysis (divergence, curl, surface integrals, contour integrals) would be nice
- I'm a great fan of analytic combinatorics, but I fear the automation we have for the kinds of asymptotic analyses that are required there are insufficient at the moment.

---